# angular waiting several subscribe to do something

Tags: angular

In a component, I subscribe to two services. the first one,

```
this.myFirstService.currentData.subscribe()
```

where currentData is from a BehaviorSubject

```
  private currentDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentData = this.currentDataSource.asObservable();
```

The second one is from an http.get

```
  getData(): Observable<Data> {
  if(localStorage.getItem('token'))
    var headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Bearer ' +   localStorage.getItem('token')});
  else
    var headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Anonymous '});

  return this.http.get<Data>("http://someurl/",{
    headers:headers,
    responseType: 'json'
  })
    .pipe();
}
```

I want to merge the datas received from both subscription. How can I archived that?

Comment: If I understand you right, you can use `zip(ovservable1, observable2).subscribe(data => {})` to wait for the data from both observables to return. (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you are using RxJs, there are a couple of ways you can do this:

#### Concat

Concat will combine two observables into a combined sequence, but the second observable will not start emitting until the first one has completed.

```
let first = Observable.timer(10,500).map(r => {
  return {source:1,value:r};
}).take(4);
let second = Observable.timer(10,500).map(r => {
  return {source:2,value:r};
}).take(4);
first.concat(second).subscribe(res => this.concatStream.push(res));
```

This will merge the two but you will receive the first observable result before the second:

```
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3
```

#### Merge

Merge is similar to concat, but it will interleave the emitted values instead of completing the first observable before starting the second one.

```
let first = Observable.timer(10,500).map(r => {
  return {source:1,value:r};
}).take(4);
let second = Observable.timer(10,500).map(r => {
  return {source:2,value:r};
}).take(4);
first.merge(second).subscribe(res => this.mergeStream.push(res));
```

You will get:

```
0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

#### forkJoin

We use forkJoin to execute observables in parallel. One common use case of this is making multiple http requests in parallel. In my sample I am forkJoining two very simple observables, but the key point is that the subscriber won't receive any values until both observables have completed.

```
let first = Observable.of({source:1,value:1});
let second = Observable.of({source:2,value:1});
Observable.forkJoin(first,second)
            .subscribe((res:Array) => this.forkJoinStream = res);
```

This would be similar to $q.all() from Angular 1.x.

And finally

#### flatMap

Use this if you have dependency between your observables. Lets say you have to get the user before you can get user details with two different http requests:

```
let first = Observable.of(10);
first.flatMap((operand1) => {
  return Observable.of(operand1 + 10);
})
.subscribe(res => this.flatMappedStreams = {msg: '10 + 10 = ' + res});
```

You will get:

```
10 + 10 = 20
```

Comment: From Angular 6 forkJoin is its own regular function and prefers array syntax forkJoin([first,second])

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `forkJoin` to merge the observables.

```
  currentData = this.currentDataSource.asObservable();
  httpReq = this.getData();

  forkJoin(currentData, httpReq ).subscribe((result) => {
    // combine results
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean to "merge" the data?

There are several ways of combining observable streams, what you'll probably need is `combineLatest` operator.

```
currentData = this.currentDataSource.asObservable();
httpData = http.getData();
currentData.pipe(combineLatest(httpData))
    .subscribe(([current, http]) => console.log(current, http));
```